# Concatenating an int variable with a string results in a strange output

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an arduino program in mind that i am trying to make.

**Its purpose:**
Read digital pins from 2, to 11.
Print the pin number, and "1" if pin is high, or "0" if pin is low.

This is what i've tried to do:

```
void loop() {
  for(int i = 2; i<12; i++){
    if(digitalRead(i) == HIGH){
      Serial.println(i + "1");
    }
    if(digitalRead(i) == LOW){
     Serial.println(i + "0");
   }
  }
}
```

**The output should be** "21" if pin 2 is `HIGH`, or "20" if pin 2 is `LOW`. The same applies to the other pins.

**Instead**, all it prints is

```
Ò>Tm_°

>Tm_°

>Tm_°

Tm_°







Ò>Tm_°

>Tm_°

>Tm_°

Tm_°
```

Any advice on how i can get this to work?

Comment: Guess what `i + "1"'` does in C. (Hint: the expression "1" evaluates to a pointer)

Comment: @immibis should i use `i+'1'`?

Comment: Use `serial.print(i); serial.println(1);`

Comment: @user3386109 thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What happen with your code ?**

`Serial.println(2 + "1")` won't give you `21` in C (in this case used for Arduino).

You are trying to concatenate an integer and a string directly and it is not valid in `C` (or almost programming language).

**Solution:**

```
void loop() {
  char pin_display;
  for(int i = 2; i<12; i++){
    if(digitalRead(i) == HIGH){
      pin_display = i + 0x30 //convert to Ascii
      Serial.print(pin_display);
      Serial.print("1");
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, the problem happens in `Serial.println(i + "1")`. This expression is evaluated as *int + pointer* that results in a corrupted *pointer*. A short way to fix that is creating a *String* from the integer variable: `Serial.println(String(i)+"1")`. This expression is evaluated as *String  + pointer* that results in a valid *String* object.

**Corrected code:**

```
void loop() {
    for(int i = 2; i<12; i++){
       if(digitalRead(i) == HIGH){
          Serial.println(String(i) + "1");
       }
       if(digitalRead(i) == LOW){
         Serial.println(String(i) + "0");
       }
    }
}
```